# How to avoid HttpAccessTokenRefreshError if the grant is deleted from list of permitted apps on Google

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth2client

I'm new to Python and oauth2client library. I'm building a def which check for a valid credentials. I noticed that if I delete the grant from https://myaccount.google.com/permissions, then credentials.get_access_token(http) or similar does returns the old access_token. The program will run only into exception when credentials.refresh(http) is called.

Is there any way I could catch this exception before the credential is refreshed?